# regex for unicode with markdown [[WikiLinks]]

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm trying to extend a JS markdown script to auto-add links when text is surrounded with double square brackets (aka wikilinks) for JAPANESE text. Now i have three problems :)

The regex result seems to not give me $1 type match elements when i have unicode being found

```
raw = "I [[carried-out]] the [[plan]]"
regex = /\[\[(\w*-*\w*)+\]\]/gm
s2 = raw.replace( regex, "<a class='link' href='/links/$1'>$1</a>" )
console.log("raw:", raw)
console.log("s2 :", s2)

#> raw: I [[carried-out]] the [[plan]]
#> s2 : I <a class='link' href='/links/carried-out'>carried-out</a> the <a class='link' href='/links/plan'>plan</a>


raw = "I [[ひらがな]] the plan [[edit]]"
regex = /\[\[[\u3040-\u309F]+\]\]/gm
s2 = raw.replace( regex, "<a class='link' href='/links/$1'>$1</a>" )
console.log("raw:", raw)
console.log("s2 :", s2)

#> raw: I [[ひらがな]] the plan [[edit]]
#> s2 : I <a class='link' href='/links/$1'>$1</a> the plan [[edit]]
```

as you can see in the second case the "$1" is not getting interpolated, even though the regex operation is almost identical?

there's a slight difference of the inner matcher:

```
regex = /\[\[(\u3040-\u309F)+\]\]/gm     # matches but no interpolation
regex = /\[\[[\u3040-\u309F]+\]\]/gm     # fails to match
```

the difference between [] and () around the match, which I'm not completely clear on:

```
(\u3040-\u309F)+
[\u3040-\u309F]+
```

Is there a known issue related to unicode? otherwise if someone could help set me straight on the  issues that would be much appreciated :)

Update: so I need to use [] for ranges, but if I do that, i don't get a match, whereas () does generate some type of match - at least it removes the matched text >.<

Unicode range matches just don't seem to be working as obviously as they should.

`[unicoderange]+` should match one or more unicode items i believe.

Thanks!

Comment: m8 show some sample strings that should match and strings that should not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i know whats the problem i tested your case and found that i worked

https://regex101.com/r/xU6qJ6/1

You probably just need to add a capture group try using this:

```
/\[\[([\u3040-\u309F]+)\]\]/gm
```

In regex stuff between () is a capture group which you can then later return

Comment: yes! this worked. mixing ranges and capture groups was what got me. the ([ - ]) syntax. who says regex isn't poetic?